# How to convert msword to epub?

Tags: epub

I need to convert a first draft of my book to .epub format. What's the best way to do it and get a clean looking book

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Save your draft as a .docx file and convert it with [Calibre](https://calibre-ebook.com/download) to an epub. 
(For best results make sure that each chapter title is formatted using a heading style, e.g., Heading 1.)

Comment: I must agree with Nemo XXX. I've used Calibre in the past, it's very easy to use with many options for advanced users. This is how I convert all my ebooks to read on my S7 Edge.

Comment: Thanx cheers for that